# How do I target a specific cells value for an If then statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to target a specific cell for my button. It is supposed to look at the cell on the active worksheet and make another worksheet active based on that cells value.(in this case the other worksheets name) If there is nothing in the cell then I want the button to do nothing.

Here is the code I have.

```
Sub Review()
If Sheets(ActiveWorkSheet).Range("F4").Value Is Nothing Then
    Else
    Sheets((ActiveWorkSheet.Range("F4").Value)).Visible = True
    Sheets((ActiveWorkSheet.Range("F4").Value)).Activate
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: `....Value = "" ...`

Comment: It Errors saying subscript is out of range.

Comment: On what line?  Is the value in the cell spelled correctly, making sure there are no spaces or other non printable characters in either that would cause it not to be found equal?

Comment: If Sheets(ActiveWorkSheet).Range("F4").Value Is Nothing Then

Comment: That line and it is a drop down list that shows as blank until something is selected. Could that be the problem?

Comment: `If ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value = "" Then`

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ActiveSheet instead

```
Sub Review()
  If Not ActiveSheet.Range("F4") Is Nothing Then
      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value).Activate
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I boiled it down to after getting Scotts help. Thank you!